# Rails: You cannot have more than one Rails::Application (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed a pesapal gem with an initializer file that looks like this;

```
# Load Pesapal config file when applicatin is loaded ... the config can then be
# accessed from PesapalRails::Application.config.yaml
module PesapalRails
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.yaml = YAML::load(IO.read("#{Rails.root}/config/pesapal.yml"))
  end
end
```

When i use it i get the error like this;

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:63:in ``inherited'``: You cannot have more than one Rails::Application (RuntimeError)
```

With a partial trace looking like this;

```
from /var/www/html/webapp/config/initializers/pesapal.rb:4:in `<module:PesapalRails>'
from /var/www/html/webapp/config/initializers/pesapal.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Why would you define `class Application` in an initializer? Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did not write it, its installed my the gem itself using `rails generate pesapal:install` Here is the gem documentation <http://rubydoc.info/gems/pesapal/>. Any advice?

Comment: Indeed, it does that. This gem is weird.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, so any advice? Can i use the pesapal.yaml file without the initializer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any advice for you here. And I really don't want to touch that gem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix**

Upgrade the gem, v1.2.1 should fix the problem ([changelog](https://github.com/itsmrwave/pesapal-rubygem/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changelog))

**Short Explanation**

Simple version ... my approach was wrong - sincere apologies. New to Ruby. New to Rails.

**Long Explanation**

The initializer was meant to create a global variable that you could access in your rails app. In my case it was `PesapalRails::Application.config.yaml`. I'd assume in your case, it was different.

The gem assumed that that global variable was set, correctly, which would bring an error since in your app `PesapalRails` doesn't exist (as you would know, the initializer is ran only when the app is started so this was kinda a safe assumption). This went undetected in my case since [my demo app](https://github.com/itsmrwave/pesapal-rails) was actually using the `PesapalRails` namespace.

**Request**

Wish you would have [filed an issue on Github - here](https://github.com/itsmrwave/pesapal-rubygem/issues?state=open) next time (it's sheer luck I stumbled on this) ... this way other devs might actually contribute to the discussion/solution. I'm willing to review and push up updates asap.